# Deserialize a nested json field with Jackson in Kotlin

Tags: kotlin, jackson

I've already deserialized some nested field in the past in Java, following instructions from https://www.baeldung.com/jackson-nested-values (section 5) :

```
@JsonProperty("brand")
private void unpackNested(Map<String,Object> brand) {
    this.brandName = (String)brand.get("name");
    Map<String,String> owner = (Map<String,String>)brand.get("owner");
    this.ownerName = owner.get("name");
}
```

`ownerName` being a field in the bean.

Now, I need to do something similar in Kotlin, but I am not happy with what I have so far. Assuming I have a `MyPojo` class that has a `createdAt` field, but in the JSON that represents it, the field is nested under a `metadata` attribute:

```
data class MyPojo(var createdAt: LocalDateTime = LocalDateTime.MIN) {

    @JsonProperty("metadata")
    private fun unpackNested(metadata: Map<String, Any>) {

        var createdAtAsString = metadata["createdAt"] as String

        this.createdAt = LocalDateTime.parse(createdAtAsString,DateTimeFormatter.ISO_DATE_TIME)
    }
}
```

One of the thing I don't like here is that I am forced to make `createdAt` a `var`, not a `val`.

Is there a Kotlin trick to make things overall better here?

Answer (score 2):

For the sake of simplicity, I used `Int` as type for `createdAt`.

You could do it like this:

```
class JsonData(createdAt: Int = 0) {

    private var _createdAt: Int = createdAt

    val createdAt: Int
        get() = _createdAt

    @JsonProperty("metadata")
    private fun unpackNested(metadata: Map<String, Any>) {
        _createdAt =  metadata["createdAt"] as Int
    }
}
```

`createdAt` will be a parameter with a default value. Since a data classe's constructor can only have properties (`var`/`val`) you will loose the advantages of a [data class](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/data-classes.html) (`toString()` out of the box etc.).

You will assign this parameter to a `private var _createdAt` when the class is instantiated.

The only thing that will be exposed to the outside is a property without a backing field `createAt` (just a getter in Java terms). So, `_createdAt` cannot be changed after instantiation.

There are two cases now:

1. If you instantiate the class, `_createdAt` will be set to the value you specify.
2. If Jackson instantiates the class the value of `_createdAt` will be overwritten by the `unpackNested` call.

Here is an example:

```
val jsonStr = """{
    "metadata": {
        "createdAt": 1
    }
}
""".trimIndent()

fun main() {
    val objectMapper = ObjectMapper()

    // Jackson does instantiation
    val jsonData = objectMapper.readValue(jsonStr, JsonData::class.java)

    // you do it directly
    JsonData(5)
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. Unfortunately, I need my class to be a ```data``` class, as I am using heavily the ```copy``` method, and I have more fields than in the simplified example I gave.

Answer (score 0):

Pls check if this works for you

```
class JsonData() {
 var createdAt by Delegates.notNull<Int>()

 @JsonProperty("metadata")
 private fun unpackNested(metadata: Map<String, Any>) {
     createdAt =  metadata["createdAt"] as Int
 }
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

You can try to do this:

```
data class MyPojo(
    var createdAt: LocalDateTime = LocalDateTime.MIN,
    @JsonProperty("metadata")
    private val metadata: Map<String, Any>
) {
    init {
        val createdAtAsString = metadata["createdAt"] as String
        createdAt = LocalDateTime.parse(createdAtAsString, DateTimeFormatter.ISO_DATE_TIME)
    }
}
```

or if you want `createAt` to be `val`, try this:

```
data class MyPojo(
    @JsonProperty("metadata")
    private val metadata: Map<String, Any>,
    val createdAt: LocalDateTime = run {
        val createdAtAsString = metadata["createdAt"] as String
        LocalDateTime.parse(createdAtAsString, DateTimeFormatter.ISO_DATE_TIME)
    }
)
```